# Is this a plausible (scientifically, not technologically or economically) way of entering space?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, orbital-motion, atmospheric-science, rocket-science, propulsion

Can a craft enter space purely by riding on the atmospheric pressure created below it?

Recently there has been a lot of hype surrounding hyperloop and about how it is a revolutionary transportation technology that takes a vehicle at unprecedented land speeds due to the lack of friction in the near-vacuum in which it travels. I've also seen many instances of people creating air-guns that rely solely on our atmospheric pressure to launch a projectile through a vacuum and out the barrel. Also, although this may seem completely unrelated, I learned that thunder is the sound of air rushing into the vacuum left after a lightning strike.

So I began to wonder if it is possible to, by creating a temporary vacuum in the atmosphere using some technology employing the lightning method, and then perhaps by using the vacuum-projectile method, gain enough momentum to leave the atmosphere where it can then begin orbital insertion via rockets?

I'd like to know if this is possible at all, if not exactly in the way I described it, perhaps in another similar way?

Comment: Why not build the hyperloop vertically?

Comment: Two main problems (among many others, imo) The channel of a lightning bolt is only about the width of a pencil, or less than half an inch, so how much energy would your system require? Also, the air temperature in the core of a lightning bolt is estimated to be around  54,000 degrees K, again an energy related problem.

Comment: nluigi & count_to_10 I know I know, this sounds absurd. However I was just wondering, say if energy was not a problem and efficiency aside, if it is theoretically possible for that kind of maneuver at all..

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean "enter space"? The X-15 and balloons can do that. If you want to *stay* up, you have to reach a speed of at least 5 miles per *second*. It's hard to see how a 20-mile tall cannon, driven only by the thin atmosphere, could accomplish that. Let me suggest another way: [*space elevator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator).

Comment: You are absolutely right. However I was just wondering if, putting technological feasibility aside, whether it is possible for the atmosphere to exert a force to the bottom of an object in such a way at all, if not sent to space.

Comment: Also I did not mean to imply pushing the object all the way to orbit, but just up through the atmosphere.

Comment: @Manta: Well, as I said, there are plenty of ways to do that. The atmosphere is not very thick.